# Replacing std::cout output with windows form

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

I made a program in c++ (visual studio 2010) that looks for serial com ports and compares their friendly names with defined text.  When there is a match that port is opened/connected and serial communication starts.

The program notifies the user when a com port is found, whether the connection was successful or not and if the data send was successful or not and other useful information. The program uses `cout` to notify the user.

I want to replace console output window with windows form but cant find much resources online on how to do this.  To illustrate, I want this:

[image: console output]

To become this:

[image: form output]

I included form1.h and other files and tried replacing `cout` with below line but code is not compiling:

```
Form1::textBox1->Text = L" Text I want to display";
```

Can anyone explain how to use textBox1, or a tutorial for this?

Comment: *"but code is not compiling"* => Always be sure to include the specific error you are getting.  Even if someone can see a problem, it might not be the only problem you have.  *(Imagine if you are seeing a "file not found" but there is also a syntax error, for instance...fixing the syntax error might not do anything for the file not found.)*  Beyond that, one should provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible--one line of code is not as good as the smallest program that demonstrates the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

"I included form1.h" - You can't just grab random files and hope it works. That is not how C++ works, or computers in general.

How then do you do something like this? The Standard Library provides `std::cout` and Visual Studio by default includes the Standard Library, so using it is fairly easy. But for graphics, you will need another library. I  recommend Qt, if only because there are good tutorials for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally did achieve the functionality I described above in my question and thought I should post my findings here.

To convert my code from console output to Windows Form I basically  had to migrate from c++ to C++/cli.

[holowczak.com](http://holowczak.com/getting-started-with-windows-forms-using-visual-c-tutorial/) has a great tutorial on how to get started with windows form (c++/cli) in visual studio.

Next if there is any busy looping(like infinite while-loop) in your c++ code then you would need to run that busy loop on a separate thread or the program can hang. [Dr.Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/ccli-threading-part-i/184402018) tutorial on how to create and mange threads in c++/cli, can help a lot.

Finally, if you need to access resources (such as textbox and other controls) of windows form from another thread then a thread-safe call has to be made.  Microsoft's "HowTo:Make thread-safe call to windows Form controls" explains how the invoke method can be used for updating textbox from another thread.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone review and edit my answer, as English is not my native language. also the link to Microsoft's[HowTo:Make thread-safe call to Windows Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)